# Codigo Javascript deja de funcionar al copiar y pegarlo de nuevo

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

por favor si a alguien mas le ha pasado que cuando ha copiado y pegado en la misma pagina su codigo javascript que contiene AJAX ha dejado de funcionar normalmente y logro solucionarlo de alguna manera, necesito su ayuda.

Mi codigo **login.js** funcionaba correctamente hasta que lo copie y lo pegue en el mismo fichero porque estuve probando algo. Ahora se detiene en la parte en la que intento enviar el formulario mediante AJAX ('Verificando credenciales...') y para que me funcione el login, tengo que recargar el buscador del navegador.

He probado con crear otro archivo js con otro nombre pero hace lo mismo

Dejo mi codigo por si a alguien se le ocurre algo

```
$(function () {
    
    'use strict';

    $("#sliderLogin").owlCarousel({

        autoplay:true,
        loop:!0,
        dots:false,
        animateOut:"fadeOut",
        animateIn:"fadeIn",
        responsive:{
            0:{items:1,dots:false},
            400:{items:1,dots:false},
            1e3:{items:1}
        }
    });

    document.getElementById('bodyApp').onload=function () {
        // body...
        var loginInicial = document.getElementById("loginInicial");

        loginInicial.classList.add('visible');

    };

    $('body').click(function(e){

        var elementoClikeado = $(e.target);

        if (elementoClikeado.parents(".cajaFormularioLogin .row").length == 1 || elementoClikeado.parents(".notificaciones").length == 1) {

        }else{
            if (elementoClikeado.is('#mostrarLogin')) {

                $('#contenedorLogin').addClass('visible');
                $('#loginInicial').removeClass('visible');

            }else{

                $('#contenedorLogin').removeClass('visible');
                $('#loginInicial').addClass('visible');
            }
        }
    });

    $('#formularioLogin').on('submit', function(event){

        event.preventDefault();
        var formulario = $(this);

        $.ajax({

            url: formulario.attr('ation'),
            type: formulario.attr('method'),
            data: formulario.serialize(),
            dataType:"json",
        //AQUI ES DONDE SE DETIENE EL LOGIN, DONDE DICE "VERIFICANDO CREDENCIALES"
            beforeSend:function()
            {
                $('#botonLogin').text('Verificando credenciales...');
                $('#botonLogin').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
            },
            success:function(respuesta){

                var mensaje = respuesa.mensaje;

                if (respuesta.exitoso == true) {

                    $('#botonLogin').text('Credenciales correctas!');
                    $('#botonLogin').attr('disabled', true);

                    mostrarMensajeExitoso(mensaje);

                    window.setTimeout(function(){

                        window.location.replace('inicio.php');
                    }, 3000);
                }else{

                    $('#botonLogin').text('Reintentar');
                    $('#botonLogin').attr('disabled', false);

                    mostrarMensajeExitoso(mensaje);
                }
            }
        })
    });
});
```

Comment: Cambiar `respuesa.mensaje` por `respuesta.mensaje` (falta una T)

Comment: @Yussef, gracias por la observacion, de todos modos, sigue sin funcionar

Comment: Una posibilidad es que falle en url: formulario.attr('ation'), probablemente debería ser action, y que al recargar esté haciendo el envío ejecutando directamente el submit.